# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' react json schema form

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

While running the sample  code for react json form schema code below , I get this error {SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'}.

Any suggestions what is incorrect here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type= "module" import React from "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script type = "module" import { render } from "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script type= "module" import Form from "https://unpkg.com/react-jsonschema-form/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type= "module" src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const schema = {
title: "Todo",
type: "object",
required: ["title"],
properties: {
title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
}
};

const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

render((
<Form schema={schema}
    onChange={log("changed")}
    onSubmit={log("submitted")}
    onError={log("errors")} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you got the packages wrong ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zum7bj

check this out its working

Comment: I was loading from cdn . Test.js should have const instead of imports.                                const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

Answer (score 0):

Is test.js located in the root directory? Usually when I see that error its because script is not being imported.